# Is there a way to have rebar generate private documentation?

Tags: documentation, erlang, rebar

In the rebar documentation, it says that making documentation supports an option called edoc_opts, which accepts options accepted by the [edoc module](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/edoc.html).

In the module's [description of the get_doc/2 function](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/edoc.html#get_doc-2), it says it accepts a proplist of options, including {private, true} to generate private documentation.

In my Makefile, I have the following:

```
docs:
    rebar skip_deps=true edoc_opts=[{private, true}] doc
```

However, rebar complains, saying that the command "true}]" is not understood or applicable.

What is the correct way to get rebar to generate private documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the option in the rebar.config file, each line is a tuple of the for {tool,[optionList]}. :

```
{edoc_opts,[{todo,true},{private,true}]}.
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the question: to get rebar to generate private documentation, you need to pass `{private, true}` in `edoc_opts` option.

You can pass this option in rebar.config file or on the command line as you do in your Makefile. In that case, you should **escape the space** or **quote the argument**. Otherwise, rebar will get `edoc_opts=[{private,` and `true}]` as two arguments.

Please note that the `rebar.config` solution feels more natural to many than using a Makefile. Properly configured, you would do `rebar doc` instead of `make docs`.